# Unable to read an URL field from an XML file using Java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

By using the code below, I was able to extract the ean,title,upc, and couple other fields from the XML file shown in picture. The problem I have is that I haven't being able to get the url stored on the "images" field.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3ODJ.png)

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display response string.
                    //Log.d("response", response);
                    output ="";
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonresponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonarray = jsonresponse.getJSONArray("items");
                        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
                        String name = jsonobject.getString("title");                     
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Description"+ name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        output = name;
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Imagen:"+output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        volleyResponseListener.onResponse(output);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

I tried the code shown below but I got an error. Can anyone please help me?

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display response string.
                    //Log.d("response", response);
                    
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonresponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonarray = jsonresponse.getJSONArray("items");
                        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
                        JSONArray imghttp = jsonobject.getJSONArray("images");
                        JSONObject imgobject = imghttp.getJSONObject(0);
                        String httpimage = imgobject.getString("images");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Articulo "+ httpimage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        
                        volleyResponseListener.onResponse(output);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

The error I'm getting is:

> "2022-10-28 13:18:38.006 9846-9846/com.example.weatherapp W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
> 2022-10-28 13:18:38.006 9846-9846/com.example.weatherapp W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> 2022-10-28 13:18:38.006 9846-9846/com.example.weatherapp W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> 2022-10-28 13:18:38.006 9846-9846/com.example.weatherapp W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
> 2022-10-28 13:18:38.007 9846-9846/com.example.weatherapp W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
> 2022-10-28 13:18:38.007 9846-9846/com.example.weatherapp W/System.err: at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
> 2022-10-28 13:18:38.007 9846-9846/com.example.weatherapp W/System.err: at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:289)"

Thanks

I would like to add I am working on building an app using Android Studio.

Comment: Hi! Is the error point to line `JSONObject imgobject = imghttp.getJSONObject(0)`?

Comment: I switched the code to this and it solved my issue.  String imageurl = httpimage.toString()